# Сменить страницу при отправке формы

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Запутался с типовой функциональностью. Помогите разобраться.
Есть входные данные, которые я объединил в форму.

```
<div>
    <form name="ticketForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
        <div>
            <label>Пункт отправления</label>
            <input type="text" name="depature" ng-model="ticket.Depature" required />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Пункт назначения</label>
            <input type="text" name="destination" ng-model="ticket.Destination" required />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Дата вылета</label>
            <input type="date" name="departureDate" ng-model="ticket.DepatureDate" required />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Дата возвращения</label>
            <input type="date" name="returnDate" ng-model="ticket.ReturnDate" required />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-disabled="ticketForm.$invalid">
    </form>
</div>
```

Вот так я отсылаю форму:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/home/Result',
            params: $scope.ticket,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
}
```

Далее вот что я хочу сделать: на стороне контроллера должны произойти вычисления, которые будут выведены посредством изменения окна. То есть фактически должна произойти переадресация. Но метод контроллера:

```
    public ActionResult Result(TicketInputData inputData)
    {
        var bestOffer = new TicketOutputData()
        {
            MinCost = 0.1,
            CompanyName = "Trololo",
            DepartureFlightNumber = "666",
            DepartureTime = DateTime.Today,
            ReturnFlightNumber = "13",
            ReturnStartTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10)
        };
        ViewBag.outputParams = bestOffer;
        return View("Result");
    }
```

К ней не приводит. Если я правильно понимаю, View создаётся, но перехода не него не происходит. Раньше я делал это через location.href ..., но теперь мне надо будет пихать в конец урла слишком много параметров. Подскажите как сделать переход на сформированное View.

И вот так тоже не работает:

```
    public RedirectToRouteResult FindResult(TicketInputData inputData)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient web = new System.Net.WebClient();
        web.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;

        string str = web.DownloadString("https://search.aviasales.ru/MOW2405ATH30061");
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(str);

        var bestOffer = new TicketOutputData()
        {
            MinCost = 0.1,
            CompanyName = "Trololo",
            DepartureFlightNumber = "666",
            DepartureTime = DateTime.Today,
            ReturnFlightNumber = "13",
            ReturnStartTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10)
        };
        //ViewBag.outputParams = bestOffer;
        //return View("Result");
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("ViewResult", "Home", bestOffer);
    }

    public ActionResult ViewResult(TicketOutputData bestOffer)
    {
        ViewBag.outputParams = bestOffer;
        return View("Result");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Парни, это сюрприз от Ангуляра, который пользуется Аяксом.
Если хотим изменить View - надо обновлять форму по старинке:

```
<form name="ticketForm" novalidate method="post" action="/Home/OnSubmit">
```